# Error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run the following code. I am getting an error that says

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The problem columns are `Policy_Txn_Date` and `Policy_Txn_Post_Date`:

```
policy_txn_date  policy_txn_post_date
--------------------------------------
20070131         20070201 
20070228         20070301 
20070331         20070401 
20070430         20070502 
20070531         20070604 
20060630         20060701
```

Code:

```
select 
    'NLFMF' as Source_code,
    gPolicy_Number_static,
    gPolicy_Number,
    PolicyNumber as Policy_Number,
    TransactionGroup,
    TransactionType,
    Txn_Amount,
    cast(Policy_Txn_Date as date) as Policy_Txn_Date,
    cast(Policy_Txn_Post_Date as date) as Policy_Txn_Post_Date
from 
    MARTDB.dbo.stg_MFCPremiums_Prepare
```

Comment: Is `Policy_Txn_Date ` an `int` or a `varchar`? If the latter, there is nothing wrong with those values (apart from being the wrong data type).

Comment: This is the statement your getting the error on?  I do not see any conversion happening to even convert to date let alone why you would be getting this error?   Is there more code your not posting  Are there spaces in those columns?

Comment: In your query you are just selecting values from table. Where from you are getting conversion related error?

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096494/how-do-i-solve-this-error-conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-fro?noredirect=1#comment100742501_57096494

Comment: what is your datatype of these 2 columns

Comment: Cannnot replicate: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e314578824a29a5145253e489462640f

Comment: Most likely, one of the values in the table is not a valid date.  For example, 20070431, or something like that.  To find it you may have to try and search it out.  For example, put a WHERE clause on the statement, and keep adjusting the value until you see which ranges work, and which range does not.

Comment: this isn't on google?  select convert(date, '20070201', 23) as Policy_Txn_Date

Answer (score 0):

Convert date in to `varchar()` and date format `112` then try to convert in `datetime`

```
select 'NLFMF' as Source_code 
    ,gPolicy_Number_static
    ,gPolicy_Number
    ,PolicyNumber as Policy_Number
    ,TransactionGroup
    ,TransactionType
    ,Txn_Amount
    ,convert(datetime, convert(nvarchar(10), Policy_Txn_Date, 112)) as Policy_Txn_Date
    ,convert(datetime,  convert(nvarchar(10), Policy_Txn_Post_Date, 112)) as Policy_Txn_Post_Date
from MARTDB.dbo.stg_MFCPremiums_Prepare
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6ae7df053b483967c2ef0256b696970)**